# Run Debug mode from command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, debugging

I want to run my project in debug mode from the command line, not from Visual Studio (VS is open).

Is there any parameter to add to the command?

Actually, I want to initialize multiple instances of my project at the same time (from bat file) and debug them - instead of pressing multiple <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Do you want to be able to debug the application as well? Otherwise simply run the app from the bin\Debug folder.

Comment: Sure I want! My vs is open.
Actually I want to initialize Multiple instances of my project at the same time (from bat file) and debug them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start your executables from the command line by just typing their (path and) name.

You can later attach to those instances using Tools/Attach to Process...

Answer (score 22):

For debugging multiple instances of your application you can launch them separately from the command line (or press Ctrl+F5 in VS to launch the application without debugger attached) and then attach the VS debugger manually using the *Debug -> Attach to Process...* menu command.

If you want to automatically launch/attach a debugger you could add the following code to your `Main` method:

```
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

This command should display the following dialog which allows you to choose the running instance for debugging:

[image: Visual Studio Just-In-Time-Debugger]

(i.e. Figure 7 in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163606.aspx)

Comment: Good Answer, But not in my case.
Because it opens new instance of vs for each instance I've
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Tools + Attach to Process allows debugging multiple processes.  In the "Available Processes" list just click + Shift click to select all of them.  Keeping track of which instance you're debugging when you set a breakpoint ought to be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework SDK includes the command-line runtime debugger named [CorDbg.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zb7c8d%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)