# Attaching Visual Studio debugger from command line

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm using `vsjitdebugger.exe -p {pid}` to attach the visual studio debugger to a running process.  It works, but with the annoyance that a popup window prompts me to select a debugger to attach and I can either choose the open instance of visual studio or start a new instance.  Is it possible to pass in the .sln file I want it to attach to so that I don't get that prompt?  I could choose new instance as the default, but I was hoping I could specify a .sln file so that it would either open that solution or attach to it if it's already open.

Thanks,
Greg

Edit:
I was hoping for a programmatic way of doing this.  My application is being run by a testing framework and I want it to run without having to click on anything.  The help dialog for vsjitdebugger.exe doesn't mention that what I want is possible.  What I really want is the ability to do: `vsjitdebugger.exe -p {pid} -s 'solution.sln'` and bypass that popup.

Comment: Are you trying to debug a process that is started by another process?

Comment: Yes.  The executable is actually being started by a testing framework written in python with subprocess.popen().  Then I follow that up with "os.system( 'vsjitdebugger.exe -p {0}'.format( self.sim_process.pid ) )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article, although it uses macro's you could convert into C# or vb.net reasonable easy.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/AttachedProcess.aspx

Comment: Thanks spgennard.  I chose this as the accepted answer because it's probably on the right track.  It looks like more trouble than it's worth though, so I may never put forth the effort to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the debugger allows the option of loading the solution when you launch it. It is not possible for the debugger to know which solution the executable belongs to as the the only argument being provided is the `pid`.

If you want to launch the process and debug it through visual studio solution, then the best way to do this would be to start the process and attach it to the debugger.

More information on how to attach to process is at [How to: Attach to a Running Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx)

Also, have a look at this question: [Run Debug mode from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855586/run-debug-mode-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I should have specified that I'm looking for a programmatic way of doing it.

Comment: @Greg McDowell, if you want to programmatically attach the process to the debugger in a specific solution, then the way ahead would be to automate visual studio to attach the process as soon as the solution is run.