# How to start a process under visual studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I use windbg and know that this is supported there. One can provide the executable to run under the debugger and any parameter that needs to be passed to it.

I am wondering whether the same is possible in Visual Studio as well. Am using Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically attach VS to running process:

[Attaching Visual Studio debugger from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717677/attaching-visual-studio-debugger-from-command-line)

just reference the EndDTE assemblies in the add reference dialog and you should be good to go

Comment: But this is to attach VS to a 'running' process (it takes pid as arg). I wish to start the process under VS (I want it to take exe and params as args).

Comment: What do you think is the benefit of forcing VS to spawn the process? That would be just unnecessary pumping of command-line parameters via VS. You can easily start the target process yourself with your own arbitrary arguments prior to having VS attach to it. As far as I know, for general debugging purposes, there's no real difference between attaching VS to running process or hitting F5 and having VS start the process. That is unless you're after some exception that occurs right after the process starts and there's no time for VS to attach or something.

Comment: Continued: If you really need VS to start the process you can experiment with manually launching vsjitdebugger.exe or using /DebugExe switch for VS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241274.aspx) both have their own "quirks" though

Comment: Yeah I want to debug a startup code. vsjitdebugger.exe method looks like an useful method here. Thanks!
/DebugExe flag seems to be useful for only c++ executables and not c# executables.