# AutoDebug when program starts

Tags: c#, debugging

in my Program in Visual Studio C# I want it to automatically start and debug when the Computer is turned on. I could manage it to start, but I couldn't make it automatically Debug, so the Program runs.
I researched it and really tried to find it, but I had no Success.

Does anybody know if there is a way to do that?
I really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Could you clarify why? There may be a better way to meet your needs, as that is a somewhat unusual request... It may be possible with `vsjitdebugger`, using `Get-Process` in PowerShell to pull out the relevant process id, but will almost certainly be somewhat painful (especially if you want it to also load Visual Studio as well).

Comment: Here is a related question though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717677/attaching-visual-studio-debugger-from-command-line

Comment: I suppose a custom VS plugin could detect that the solution ended up loading and could call the debug command from there, but I really can't see why you'd want that.

Comment: What I want. I have in my computer Visual Studio Shell and Visual Studio c#. The Shell version makes lots of tests and write the results in a .csv file. The C# version takes this .csv file and a Excel file and writes the .csv file in the Excel. I had to do like that because of some restrictions from the versions I have.
What I want now is to turn my computer on and both of the programs run automatically, without the need to press any other button. So that's the surrounding from my question. Does it help to clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Make a shorcut to Startup with the command like the one below

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /Run [SolutionNameWithFullPath]

Comment: Or you could use the [/DebugExe {path_to_exe}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241274.aspx) flag - +1 CuriousPen :)

Comment: @RB. Here are all the [Devenv Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure If I understand you right but in some cases I have found useful `Debugger.Launch()` method right where I want start debug. I'm using it while debugging Windows services for example where you can't simply run code from Visual Studio.

Comment: Not related to the author's question, but if you use `TopShelf` ([NuGet Link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/)) you can really easily write a Windows Service that can be installed as a service or run as a console application - I use it for all my Windows Service needs :)

Comment: Thanks for interesting link. I'll definitely give it show at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: The question is how to make this process automatic.

Comment: I suppose that problem is that user3497891 wants debug program which starts simultaneously with PC. Debugger.Launch() stops execution of program and takes you to place of code where you have this method call very similar like "set breakpoint" do it.