# Launching MSVC debugger to debug an app from command line without clicking on pop-ups

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, command-line

We want our continuous integration scripts to run our apps on the test environments with MSVC attached to the apps.

I've tried several options like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855586/run-debug-mode-from-command-line) or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.90).aspx) that launch **vsjitdebugger.exe** but it pops several pop-ups like "Do you really want to start debgging? Yes. Cancel debugging" and "Choose the debugger"( with only one choice in the list). That is unacceptable because ... it is supposed to be automated - to work without humans.

Anyone done that and knows how to truly automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have the JIT debugging pop windows during using command line or IDE if we enable JIT debugging to capture the Exception, I often use the following sample as the debugging tool even if it doesn't really meet your requirement:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1090417/how-to-set-debugger-to-auto-attach-on-process-star

We could disable JIT without pop window, but it means that it will not really call it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.140).aspx

No other good workaround for it, but I will help you submit a feature request to the product team:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17280578-launching-msvc-debugger-to-debug-an-app-from-comma

You could add your comment and vote it:)